# Fortran kind of matrix creation

Tags: matrix

I want to create the matrix H of dimensions nxn and matrix elements H(i,j). Because of the physical problem I am dealing with, it is necessary to build it in the following not trivial way.
I know how to do it in Fortran, but this time I have not been able to figure out how to do it in Wolfram Mathematica.

FORTRAN WAY:

```
  do iy=1,n

     do ix=1,n

        do jy=1,n

           do jx=1,n

            i = ix+(iy-1)*n

            j = jx+(jy-1)*n

     (Now I give a list of "If" about i and j, and give values to my matrix elemnts H(i,j))

            enddo
        enddo
    enddo
enddo
```

Does anybody know how to do this in Wolfram Mathematica?

Comment: Have you looked at the docs for the `Do` command?

Comment: Are you sure you want the inner `If` in terms of `i`, `j` - and not in terms of `ix`, `iy`, `jx`, `jy`? The latter seems more natural and would probably make it easier to write this in a more *Mathematica* friendly way.

Comment: You can use `Table` to build a rank 4 array, and then use `Flatten` to flatten it down to a rank 2 matrix.

Comment: This quadruple loop is really a double loop over `i` and `j` ranging from `1` to `n^2` each. That's inconsistent with claiming `H` is an `n` by `n` matrix:it has to be `n^2` by `n^2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a pretty direct translation using the simple pattern `do x=min,max code enddo`->`Do[code,{x,min,max}]`. Note that because the code now comes before the iterator specification it looks like they have been reversed, they in fact traveres the same way as your Fortran code.

```
H=ConstantArray[0,{n+(n-1)n,n+(n-1)n}];
Do[
    Do[
        Do[
            Do[
            (
            i=ix+(iy-1)*n;
            j=jx+(jy-1)*n;
            If[j>2&&i<3,H[[i,j]]="X",H[[i,j]]="y"]
            )
            ,{jx,1,n}]
        ,{jy,1,n}]
    ,{ix,1,n}]
,{iy,1,n}]
```

I just put some arbitrary `If` structure to show how you'd do it. This all comes fairly easy if you skim through the docs. In fact if you look at the doc for `Do` you'll find that it supports multiple iterators, meaning you could also put all the iterators in a single call to it:

```
H=ConstantArray[0,{n+(n-1)n,n+(n-1)n}];
Do[(
    i=ix+(iy-1)*n;
    j=jx+(jy-1)*n;
    If[j>2&&i<3,H[[i,j]]="X",H[[i,j]]="y"]
),{iy,1,n},{ix,1,n},{jy,1,n},{jx,1,n}]
```

Comment: When specifying multiple iterators the order is the reverse of when you nest them. See last bullet in the Details section of the doc page.